# Is there a canonical example of how to use Antlr 4 to parse SQL statements?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, antlr4

I am trying to build a parser using Antlr4 for SQL statements.  I don't really care which particular grammar of SQL I use, as I plan to enforce that only ANSI SQL is allowed, but in the example below I happen to be using the grammar for T-SQL.  Here is my simple code:

```java
String sql = "SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) FROM some_table";
TSqlLexer tSqlLexer = new TSqlLexer(CharStreams.fromString(sql));
CommonTokenStream stream = new CommonTokenStream(tSqlLexer);
TSqlParser parser = new TSqlParser(stream);
ParseTree tree = parser.tsql_file();  // errors happen here
ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
// I built a custom listener, so far not much in it
AnalyticFunctionBaseListener listener = new AnalyticFunctionBaseListener();
walker.walk(listener, tree);
```

The code only gets as far as the call to `tsql_file()` before generating the following errors/warnings:

```
line 1:35 token recognition error at: 'i'
line 1:36 token recognition error at: 'd'
line 1:44 token recognition error at: 's'
line 1:45 token recognition error at: 'o'
line 1:46 token recognition error at: 'm'
line 1:47 token recognition error at: 'e'
line 1:49 token recognition error at: 't'
line 1:50 token recognition error at: 'a'
line 1:51 token recognition error at: 'b'
line 1:52 token recognition error at: 'l'
line 1:53 token recognition error at: 'e'
line 1:37 no viable alternative at input 'SELECTROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDERBY)'
```

There is clearly something major I am missing here, but I don't what that is.  I built using the published grammars for TSQL available at the [ANTLR GitHub site](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/sql/tsql).

Can any Antlr guru modify the above snippet so that it works?  I am hoping someone can give a canonical example of how to use Antlr to parse a basic SQL statement.

Comment: Fun! I'll bookmark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the following comment in the [README](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/tsql/README.md):

> #### Usage, important note
>
> As SQL grammar are normally not case sensitive but this grammar implementation is, you must use a custom [character stream](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/CharStream.java) that converts all characters to uppercase before sending them to the lexer.
>
> You could find more information [here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/case-insensitive-lexing.md#custom-character-streams-approach) with implementations for various target languages.

In short, change your code:

```java
String sql = "SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) FROM some_table";
TSqlLexer tSqlLexer = new TSqlLexer(CharStreams.fromString(sql));
```

to:

```java
String sql = "SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) FROM some_table";
CharStream s = CharStreams.fromString(sql);
TSqlLexer tSqlLexer = new TSqlLexer(new CaseChangingCharStream(s, true));
```

Find the source of `CaseChangingCharStream` here: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/resources/CaseChangingCharStream.java

### EDIT

In the comments, Mike suggests:

> Alternatively you can use the [MySQL grammar](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/tree/8.0/library/parsers/grammars), which supports case-insensitive keywords without an extra stream

which might be a better option. I'm not saying the T-SQL grammar isn't good/accurate, but the fact that Mike's suggested grammar comes from the official MySQL repo (and Mike contributed to it), would give me confidence in the quality of it.

Comment: Alternatively you can use the [MySQL grammar](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/tree/8.0/library/parsers/grammars), which supports case-insensitive keywords without an extra stream.

Comment: Added your comment to my answer @MikeLischke

Comment: @BartKiers Thanks for this very helpful answer, for certain it resolved the problem described in the question +1.